# (Flutter) CRUD SQFlite my Lists code outputs into null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My List tile always outputs into null it says before in this line before I casts my list to string
child: ListTile(
subtitle: Text(_contacts[index]['Phone Number']),
title: Text(_contacts[index]['First Name ']+_contacts[index]['Last Name'],

it says
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

this is my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'sql_helper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Nagal-Contacts - Crud',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF3E3E3E)
        ),
        home: const HomePage(title: 'Nagal-Contacts - Crud')
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // All contacts

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _contacts = [];
  final TextEditingController _firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _phonenumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _addressController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _dobController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _refreshContacts();
  }
  void _refreshContacts() async {
    final data = await SQLHelper.getItems();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = data;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
  void _showForm(int? id) async {
    DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();
    _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
      var _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: _currentDate,
          firstDate: DateTime(2015),
          lastDate: DateTime(2050));
      if (_pickedDate != null) {
        setState(() {
          _currentDate = _pickedDate;
          _dobController.text = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_pickedDate).toString();
        });
      }
    }
//Form Add
    if (id != null) {
      final existingContact =
      _contacts.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == id);
      _firstnameController.text = existingContact['firstname'];
      _lastnameController.text = existingContact['lastname'];
      _phonenumberController.text = existingContact['phonenumber'];
      _addressController.text = existingContact['address'];
      _emailController.text = existingContact['email'];
      _dobController.text = existingContact['dob'];
    }
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        elevation: 5,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (_) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 15,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            // this will prevent the soft keyboard from covering the text fields
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 120,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _firstnameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'First Name'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _lastnameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Last Name'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _phonenumberController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Phone Number'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _addressController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Address'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _dobController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Date Of Birth',
                prefixIcon: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){_selectDate(context);
                    },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Save new contact
                  if (id == null) {
                    await _addItem();
                  }

                  if (id != null) {
                    await _updateItem(id);
                  }

                  // await addItem();
                  _firstnameController.text = '';
                  _lastnameController.text = '';
                  _phonenumberController.text = '';
                  _addressController.text = '';
                  _emailController.text = '';
                  _dobController.text = '';
                  // Close the bottom sheet
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

//Function -> Add
  Future<void> _addItem() async {
    await SQLHelper.createItem(
        _firstnameController.text,
        _lastnameController.text,
        _phonenumberController.text,
        _addressController.text,
        _emailController.text,
        _dobController.text,
    );
    _refreshContacts();
  }

  // Function -> Update
  Future<void> _updateItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.updateItem(
        id, _firstnameController.text, _lastnameController.text,
      _addressController.text,_phonenumberController.text,_emailController.text,_dobController.text);
    _refreshContacts();
  }

  // Function -> Delete
  void _deleteItem(int id) async {
    await SQLHelper.deleteItem(id);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Successfully deleted a contact!'),
    ));
    _refreshContacts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Nagal-Contacts Crud'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
             )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _contacts.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          color: Colors.black38,
              child: ListTile(
              subtitle: Text(_contacts[index]['Phone Number'].toString()),
              title: Text(_contacts[index]['First Name '].toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      // height: 5,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF))),
              trailing: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                      onPressed: () => _showForm(_contacts[index]['id']),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                      onPressed: () =>
                          _deleteItem(_contacts[index]['id']),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _showForm(null);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my sql_helper.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;

class SQLHelper {
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE items(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        firstname TEXT,
        lastname TEXT,
        phonenumber TEXT,
        address TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        dob DATETIME,
        createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      )
      """);
  }
// id: the id of a item
// firstname, lastname: name and lastname of your activity
// created_at: the time that the item was created. It will be automatically handled by SQLite

  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    return sql.openDatabase(
      'contactscrud.db',
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
        await createTables(database);
      },
    );
  }

  // Create new item (contacts)
  static Future<int> createItem(String firstname, String lstname,
      String phonenumber, String address, String email, String dob) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();

    final data =
    {'firstname': firstname,
      'lastname': lstname,
      'phonenumber': phonenumber,
      'address' : address,
      'email': email,
      'dob':dob,
    };
    final id = await db.insert('items', data,
        conflictAlgorithm: sql.ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return id;
  }

  // Read all items (journals)
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('items', orderBy: "id");
  }

  // Read a single item by id
  // The app doesn't use this method but I put here in case you want to see it
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItem(int id) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query('items', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id], limit: 1);
  }

  // Update an item by id
  static Future<int> updateItem(
      int id, String firstname, String lstname,
      String phonenumber, String address, String email, String dob) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();

    final data = {
      'firstname': firstname,
      'lastname': lstname,
      'phonenumber': phonenumber,
      'address' : address,
      'email': email,
      'dob': dob,
      'createdAt': DateTime.now().toString()
    };

    final result =
    await db.update('items', data, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return result;
  }

  // Delete
  static Future<void> deleteItem(int id) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    try {
      await db.delete("items", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    } catch (err) {
      debugPrint("Something went wrong when deleting an item: $err");
    }
  }
}
```

I tried casting it toString but all the data in the lists results into null
What am I missing logic at my code? Can someone help me :<

Answer (score 0):

As I saw your code,

There were naming issues, in DB you define `phonenumber`, `firstname` and tried to fetch using `'Phone Number'` and `'First Name '` respectively.

Please, replace line no 211-212 in main.dart

```
subtitle: Text(_contacts[index]['phonenumber'].toString()),
title: Text(_contacts[index]['firstname'].toString(),
```